# Regex for fixed number in javascript/jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, regex

I want to validate textfield for user to enter only number like..
It should start from 'ARRN' and upto 5 numeric fields.
So number can be.. ARRN1 OR ARRN12 OR ARRN123 BUT NOT ARRN123456 AS ONLY 5 NUMERIC ALLOWED.

Can I have regex for the same in javascript to validate?

I tried with regex ['ARRN'@[5]] But not sure about regex syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the follwong code to check that pattern. It will check the pattern in `onblur` event of the input.

```
$('input').on('blur',function(){
   var val = $(this).val();

   if(/^ARRN\d{1,5}$/.test(val))
      alert('Val is Ok');
   else
   {
     //$(this).val('');
     alert('Val is not correct.');  
   }       
});​
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/3MtDa/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use an expression like this:

```
^ARRN\d{1,5}$
```

Which would work in JS and .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+{5,9}$/
```

{5,9} means minimum ARRN + 1 num To maximum ARRN + 5 nums